# Laravel and Mysql count related models through pivot with additional condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a mysql query (Built using Laravel Eloquent's eager loading and withCount functions), which has some performance issues with big data sets, is there any way to improve this query below?

I need to get all the shops, and the count of products related to the shop (through pivot), but additional condition is also, that shops.type_id equals products.type_id. I think that this second condition is causing me issues with the queries not using correct indexes.

There is a pivot table between the two models.

shops (id, type_id, owner_id)
products (id, type_id)
shop_product (shop_id, product_id)

I have indexes on all of the foreign keys, and also a composite index on shop_product (shop_id, product_id)

So my query is like this:

```
select
    shops.*,
    (
    select
        count (*)
    from
        products
    inner join shop_products on
        products.id = shop_products.product_id
    where
        shops.id = shop_products.shop_id
        and products.type_id = shops.type_id)
from
    shops
where
    shops.owner_id in (?)
```

is it possible that this query could be optimized somehow, maybe not using this laravel's withCount whereColumn query?

```
... Shop::withCount(['products' => fn($query) => $query->whereColumn('products.type_id', '=', 'shops.type_id')]);
```

Full query is like this:

```
Shop::whereIn('owner_id', [123])
            ->withCount(['products' => fn($query) => $query->whereColumn('products.type_id', '=', 'shops.type_id')])
            ->get()
```

Do i maybe need to add composite indexes on shops (id, type_id), and products (id, type_id) ?

Answer (score -1):

I did not test this one but I'd try something like:

```
Shop::whereIn('owner_id', [123])
            ->withCount(['products' => fn($query) => $query->select(['id','type_id'])->whereColumn('products.type_id', '=', 'shops.type_id')])
            ->get()
```

So I have just added select couple of fields (the one you need and the one app needs to recognise product - but if you need only count I would try without ID too).

I assume when you get "products" it pulls all the data and it will be slow especially if there are "text" type fields like body/description etc.

Also, not sure but you could try instead of `'products.type_id'` to do `type_id` since you are already in 'products' relationship. Also you can check to optimize pull of `shops`.

Comment: when doing a count, mysql needs to retrieve the whole row anyway, so doing a subselect will not help me improve the performance.

Comment: you are right then prob the one way to go would be prober db indexing